I would like to batch (with a command line) the "reparation" of LibreOffice (odt mainly) corrupted files
I have received a quite large collection of LibreOffice odt files, which are corrupted (for a reason still unknown). When opening most of them, LibreOffice proposes to repair/fix them, and it looks like I'm able to recover them, eventually, which is good.
However, since there are a few tens of them, I'd like to be able to batch/script that.
I did not find any tool that proposes it, did I miss something ?
"unoconv" does not seem to do the job.
I also tried to investigate what I could directly change myself within the file format, comparing the contents before and after "reparation". However, the corrupted one is not "unzip"-able, because of

End-of-central-directory signature not found.

Does anybody know a way to achieve that (fixing a corrupted odt file with a command-line) ? Better with a Linux computer.

In a business environment, which is ServerFault all about, the proper answer could only be "restore corrupted files from backup". If you are expecting a help in working with LibreOffice from command line, or with recovery of files, SuperUser is probably the best place to ask.
